# How can Guava just cast future to listenable future?

Tags: java, asynchronous, guava

Exploring the classes in guava to understand the benefits what guava brings, even though with the introduction of java 8, it does not matter that much now, but I am still wondering about how listenableFuture is introduced.

in [AbstractListeningExecutorService](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractListeningExecutorService.java), there is code snippet like this:

```
  @Override
  public ListenableFuture<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    return (ListenableFuture<?>) super.submit(task);
  }
```

here `super` indicates the super class of AbstractListeningExecutorService, namely ExecutorService, but how can we just cast a superclass (Future) to a subclass (ListenableFuture) like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice the direct superclass of `AbstractListeningExecutorService` is [`AbstractExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) which

> Provides default implementations of `ExecutorService` execution methods.
>   This class implements the submit, `invokeAny` and `invokeAll` methods
>   using a `RunnableFuture` returned by `newTaskFor`, which defaults to the
>   `FutureTask` class provided in this package.

That default is overriden in [`AbstractListeningExecutorService`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractListeningExecutorService.html)

> Abstract `ListeningExecutorService` implementation that creates
>   `ListenableFuture` instances for each `Runnable` and `Callable` submitted to
>   it

You can also see that in the source code you linked to

```
  /** @since 19.0 (present with return type {@code ListenableFutureTask} since 14.0) */
  @Override
  protected final <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    return TrustedListenableFutureTask.create(runnable, value);
  }
```

That `create` returns a [`TrustedListenableFutureTask`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TrustedListenableFutureTask.java) value, which is a subtype of `ListenableFuture`.

Those methods in `AbstractListeningExecutorService` are redeclared so that their return type can be made more specific, ie. `ListenableFuture`.

Since `super.submit(..)` has a return type of `Future`, the return value must be cast to the appropriate subtype, ie. `ListenableFuture` in this case. And since all calls return the instance created by `newTaskFor`, it is known that they will be instances of type `ListenableFuture`. The cast is therefore safe.

Comment: just read the template method pattern, but did not realize its application like this, thanks